# Flip a coin, if it is'Head' continue, flipping until 'Tail' shows up. When 'Tail happens, stop the game and return the number of 'Head' (using Python

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import random
def game():
    numHead=0
    outcome=['Head','Tail']
    result=random.choice(outcome)
    while result !='Tail':
        numHead +=1
        break
    return numHead
```

Is this correct? It seems something wrong here but I couldn't figure it out..Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `break` and your `while` condition should be:

```
while random.choice(outcome) !='Tail'
```

Working version:

```
import random
def game():
    numHead=0
    outcome=['Head','Tail']
    while random.choice(outcome) !='Tail':
        numHead +=1
    return numHead
```